# Solr-CustomTransformer For Converting Data from Database to table data

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I am quite new to the solr custom transformer. I am trying to use solr custom customtransformer for preprocessing of the data fetched from Database. 
The basic problem that, I am getting in using custom transformer, There is no change in the resultant row of solr after importing the data. I have checked that, Class is loaded and there is no error of

`Error loading class of cust.test.pretransform`

And In the transformer code, I just want the code to be reacted to the code.

```
public Object transformRow(Map<String, Object> row, Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    List<Map<String, String>> fields = context.getAllEntityFields();
    for (Map<String, String> field : fields) {  
        String textstruk_tec = field.get("field_tec");
        if("name".equals(textstruk_tec))
        {
             String columnName = field.get(DataImporter.COLUMN);
             Object values = row.get(columnName);
             if(values != null)
             {
                row.put(textstruk_tec, "Textteil");
             }
        }
    }

return row; 
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Best Regards !

Comment: Do you see your .jar file being loaded in the Solr startup log?

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger to see if your code is actually invoked? Or at least added a set of print statements?

Comment: I was able to load the jar file and it is working as per expectations.